# Azure OPDG System Aggregation Logs to TimeChart in KQL

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, azure-log-analytics, kql

I am ingesting Azure OPDG System Aggregation logs from an Azure Monitoring Agent to an Azure Log Analytics Workspace. Each log is collected by timestamp and I am using Custom filters to separate out the `CounterMin`, `CounterMax`, `CounterAverage` and `CounterName`. The 4 types of `CounterName` are `GatewayCPUPercent`, `SystemCPUPercent`, `SystemMEMUsedPercent` and `GatewayMEMKb`. Unfortunately that last value, `GatewayMEMKb`, is not in a percentage of the Systems Total Memory, so tracking these 4 values on a timechart doesn't work.

I'd like to convert the `GatewayMEMKb` to a `GatewayMEMUsedPercent`, and I have the value of the total memory of the server so should be able to do this, but I can't find out how to extract just those values of the `CounterAverage` column depending on the content of the `CounterName` column.

I realise this may need to be achieved using a separate column, but can't figure out how to do it.

Initial data:

| CounterName | CounterAverage |
| --- | --- |
| GatewayCPUPercent | 15 |
| SystemCPUPercent | 45 |
| SystemMEMUsedPercent | 30 |
| GatewayMEMKb | 327,678 |
| GatewayCPUPercent | 14 |
| SystemCPUPercent | 48 |
| SystemMEMUsedPercent | 31 |
| GatewayMEMKb | 356,876 |

Desired outcome:

| CounterName | CounterAverage | GatewayMEMUsedPercent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GatewayCPUPercent | 15 |  |
| SystemCPUPercent | 45 |  |
| SystemMEMUsedPercent | 30 |  |
| GatewayMEMKb | 327,678 | 2.5 |
| GatewayCPUPercent | 14 |  |
| SystemCPUPercent | 48 |  |
| SystemMEMUsedPercent | 31 |  |
| GatewayMEMKb | 356,876 | 2.8 |

Answer (score 1):

The following query will transform the input you've provided into the output you've provided.

It uses the `iff()` function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/ifffunction

```
let total_memory_bytes = 12.4 * exp2(30);
datatable(CounterName:string, CounterAverage:double)
[
    'GatewayCPUPercent', 15,
    'SystemCPUPercent', 45,
    'SystemMEMUsedPercent', 30,
    'GatewayMEMKb', 327678,
    'GatewayCPUPercent', 14,
    'SystemCPUPercent', 48,
    'SystemMEMUsedPercent', 31,
    'GatewayMEMKb', 356876,
]
| extend GatewayMEMUsedPercent = iff(CounterName == 'GatewayMEMKb', round(100.0 * CounterAverage * 1024/total_memory_bytes, 2), double(null))
```

| CounterName | CounterAverage | GatewayMEMUsedPercent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GatewayCPUPercent | 15 |  |
| SystemCPUPercent | 45 |  |
| SystemMEMUsedPercent | 30 |  |
| GatewayMEMKb | 327678 | 2.52 |
| GatewayCPUPercent | 14 |  |
| SystemCPUPercent | 48 |  |
| SystemMEMUsedPercent | 31 |  |
| GatewayMEMKb | 356876 | 2.74 |